# Creating custom exception in java in a single class is bad practice?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Collision  extends Exception {
    
    static String s1, s2 = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter diection of first vehicle");
        s1 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter direction of second vehicle");
        s2 = sc.nextLine();
        try {
                if(s1.equals(s2))
                {
                    System.out.println("everything is fine no exception");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Collision();
                }
        }
    catch(Collision e) {
        System.out.println("this is a exception ");
    }
        sc.close(); 
    }

}
```

Q1) In the above code I am catching a custom exception in the same class, is this considered as bad practice as most of the tutorials on web either create a different class in the same Java program or create a separate class file. Should I change this code by creating a class for the exception?

Q2) I also wanted to create multiple exceptions but as I searched the internet even though I found some tutorials on creating custom exceptions but not a single one that told how to implement multiple custom exceptions it. Any link or a past question or some kind of documentation to explain this would be really helpful

Comment: you shouldn't be throwing an exception there, you should have new input instead. This is not something your system can't recover from.

Comment: About Q2 (leaving aside the fact that you should ask only one question per post), what do you mean? If you want more than one custom exception just create more than one and throw the appropriate one when needed.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca sure I will ask it in another post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to have the custom exceptions classes outside the main code, better in separate files

```
public class Test {
    static String s1, s2 = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter diection of first vehicle");
        s1 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter direction of second vehicle");
        s2 = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            if (s1.equals(s2)) {
                System.out.println("everything is fine no exception");
            } else {
                if (s1.equals("FOO")) {
                    throw new IncorrectWord("Foo is an incorrect word");
                } else {
                    throw new Collision();
                }
            }
        } catch (Collision | IncorrectWord e) {
            System.out.println("this is a exception ");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Errors, put it in separate files

```
class Collision extends Exception {
}

class IncorrectWord extends Exception {
    public IncorrectWord(String errorMessage) {
        super(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- If your class throws an exception and catches it, it means it knows how to deal with it. We throw an exception only when we know we can't process the result. It is redundant to do so.
- It is definitely a bad practise to have Exception in same class as where our business code is. It violates separation of concern.
  Your class should only extend and not be modified. But if your exception changes, you are modifying same class.
- Also you could use your exception in different class which shouldn't know anything about this main method.
- you could add multiple classes extending Exception, or maybe a generic exception extended by a specific exception. You could place all these under a single package or if they are very close, in a separate file.